# Amazon Snap shot Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, snapshot, readonly

I had a snapshot in my amazon VPC account, which should not be deleted by any one. So is there any option in amazon for making the snapshot read only or not deleted by any one.

Answer (score 0):

If a person has sufficient privileges to the account, they will be able to delete it; if you are really worried throw a copy on S3 and make sure no one has access to it except you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... But  is there any option to add any acl permissions on those snap shots to make it read only.